# Running mongoDB on startup on Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, startup, sudo

I have set up Mongo to run on a GCE instance.

At first I was working in `/` and launching mongo with `sudo mongod`, but reasonably it prints some warning about that:

> WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, 
>   which is not recommended.

So I moved everything to `/home/my_google_account`, and I can just get in through SSH and run `mongod`.

**Now I’d like to have some actions, including `mongod`, run at startup**. From my understanding, the right way to do this is to use [Google startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript): from the console you can provide a script like the following as a metadata key-value pair:

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get update
mongod -f /home/my_google_account/mongod.conf
```

**It works**, but as Google says, this is executed as root:

> The instance always executes startup scripts as root, and only
>   executes those scripts after it creates any new users whose SSH keys
>   are included in the instance metadata.

So the mongod process is run with root privileges and I still get the warning that I had originally:

> WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, 
>   which is not recommended.

What should I do?

Is there a way for a startup script not to run as root?
Or should I just work in `/` with `sudo`s and ignore the warning at all?
Everybody seems to suggest that you should work in your user’s home folder, get the necessary permissions, and run mongod with your privileges. But then the startup script will run as root anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - add a user to your persistent disk -

```
useradd -ms /bin/bash mongouser
#replace /data/db with your data location
chown -R mongouser /data/db
```

add this to your starup script

```
apt-get update
sudo mongouser -c 'mongod -f /home/my_google_account/mongod.conf'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope you can clear my mind about this. I have noticed actually that my mongo build (from percona.com) already created a `mongod` user in a `mongod` group. What is that for? Am I supposed to use that one (e.g. `sudo mongod -c 'mongod -f mongod.conf`)?

Comment: most likely it is for running mongo. If you are using a non-standard package build i would guess that your build might also 'chown' the mongo data dir to the 'mongod' user for you. Check and see which user/group owns the /data/db dir (or start mongo as root like you already do and ps -eaf | grep mongo to see where the mongo data dir is with a --dbpath config or look in /home/my_google_account/mongod.conf for location). You can use mongod or any user as long as owns the data dir... And please mark answer as correct ;-)